# Does the isEqual implementation for NSSet and NSArray use isEqualToSet and isEqualToArray internally?

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsset

In case of either a `NSSet` or a `NSArray`, it would make sense for the `isEqual` implementation to simply delegate to `isEqualToSet` and `isEqualToArray`, respectively. But I can't be sure if that is what actually happens. Anyone know for sure via past experience?

Answer (score 0):

On my past experience that methods are equal.

The main difference is that by using `isEqualToSet` or `isEqualToArray` the compiler will be able to check types (classes) of parameters.

Comment: I understand the difference between isEqual and the more specialized versions, my question is if the implementation of isEqual for these classes delegates forward to isEqualToSet / isEqualToArray or not?

Comment: Check my question one more time

Comment: Care to re-phrase this - "On my past experience that methods are equal." I don't get it.